# rails 3.1, how to use before_filter to call method at a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to call a method defined in a helper which uses `content_for`, I need to render some buttons& links at lots of views.

The question is, how can I benefit from the before_filter ? I know its not designed for helpers, so, what's the proper way to do so ?

Currently, I am calling the helper method at most of views, which seems not practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling a method in a bunch of views, you probably want to put it in the application layout (by default `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`)

Answer (score 3):

A `before_filter` will not be of any help here. A `before_filter` is used inside the controller, to execute method before starting an action. Generally, what one does:

- verify authentications/access/authorisations
- retrieve data
- it can also be used to refactor code that is shared between controller methods

In your case, what I would consider are:

- using a partial, to share the common view-part
- use different layout, instead of `application.html.erb` to group the shared views together
- push the shared view-part to `application.html.erb`

Hope this helps.